# Calculating date difference

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm calculating the age of a user by subtracting his age from today's date. The problem I have is that it show their age as whole number. But rather than showing it as a whole number, I'd like to display it as decimal like 25.5 or 27.3. I tried using round and number_format but neither worked.

```
$bday = $data->_field_data['node_field_data_field_game_players_nid']['entity']->field_player_birthday['und'][0]['value'];
$now = date("Y/m/d");
$diff = ($now) - date($bday);
echo number_format(round($diff, 2), 2);
```

Comment: `date` brings back a string, you can't subtract that. What is `$bday`? Maybe look at `strtotime` or http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a `DateTime`/`DateTimeImmutable` object?

Comment: so `$difference = strtotime($now)- strtotime($bday);` would give me to the time stamp difference, and convert it back to year?

Comment: Yes, you could just use `time()` for the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$bday = $data->_field_data['node_field_data_field_game_players_nid']['entity']->field_player_birthday['und'][0]['value'];
echo  number_format(round((strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) - strtotime($bday))/(60*60*24*365),2),2);
```

However, above calculation is very rough.  if you want get value more precisely you should use date_diff for that:

```
$bday = $data->_field_data['node_field_data_field_game_players_nid']['entity']->field_player_birthday['und'][0]['value'];
$date1=date_create($bday); //create date object
$date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d")); //create date object
$curyearmaxdays=date("z", mktime(23,59,59,12,31,date("y")))+1; //count of days in the current year
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2); //difference between two date objects
$realdiff=$diff->y + $diff->m/12+$diff->d/$curyearmaxdays;
echo  number_format(round($realdiff,2),2);
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!!